# How to run an Executable that needs packages without internet?

Tags: python

I have a Script, which using pyinstaller I turned into an Executable.

The issue is  I need to be able to run this Script on PC which a) don't have Python installed, and b) no access to internet, and c) the Script used a bunch of packages.

So is there a way in which I can include Pyhton, and the packages into my Executable?

My import statements in my Script look like this:

```
import os
import datetime
import time
import magic
import json
from dateutil.parser import parse
import sys
import json
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image  
from tkinter import *
```

AND libmagic needs to be installed as well..

Is it possible to include them into my executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using the `Pyinstaller` package, I'm assuming that the issue is for the packages which aren't imported in the python file as `Pyinstaller` automatically adds all the imported packages to the executable file. You can use the argument `--hidden-import` for the packages that you can't or don't want to mention in the file. For example,

```bash
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import libmagic app.py
```

See its documentation [here](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-hidden-import).

Comment: Thanks! Does Pyinstaller download Python automatically as well, or do I need to do something for that?

Comment: Once the executable file is created, it doesn't require anything to be downloaded. It takes care of both Python and the packages. When you run the `pyinstaller` command, make sure you're running it in an environment that has all the packages and right python version installed. For example, create a conda or virtual environment first and install all the required packages with required versions and then run the `pyinstaller` command.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to py2exe, I use this one and I don't have any issues. It works without internet and it transform all your packages.

Create a programm in the same path which the programm you want to transform. Call it `setup.py` and complete it with :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['yourprogramm.py'])
```

Don't forget to install the package before `pip install py2exe`

When your programm is created open a terminal in your programm path with `cd` command and type :

`python setup.py py2exe`

You finally get a dist folder and your executable will be in :)